# Slow net on imac but fine all other devices

Tags: network, wifi, imac

As suggested internet speed on my imac is slow(0.04 Mbps down) but all other devices are slow. This occurred after restarting chrome, upon reopen of chrome WiFi stopped working. After restart 0.04 Mbps.

Imac 21.5 inch later 2015-
Mac os Mojave-
Intel processor 1.6 GHz i5

Solutions tried:

- clearing cache
- dns flush
- new network location(renew dhcp lease, adding 2 DNS servers,manual mtu 1491)
- deleting internet settings within /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration
- different network
- new user profile
- 2.4 and 5 GHz network
- deleting nord vpn

When trying to reinstall macos, the request to the recovery server failed.

Channel:4
Rssi: -68 dBm
Noise: -95 dBm
Tx rate: 130 Mbps
MCS index: 15

I'm out of all Solutions, can't reinstall os due to the recovery server issue. Any and all help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does it only occur in Chrome or also in other browsers (or applications accessing the Internet)? Does it change if you restart your WiFi router?

Comment: Does it happen in Safe Mode?

Comment: It occurs across all browsers and programs. To confirm, to enter safemode you hold down shift on start up. If so I did so and my computer got really buggy. I'll try again and report back.

Comment: Apologies for late replies, when I safemode as previously I can't even use chrome. Everything is black or greyed out. It did load one loading bar for my speedtest and it took equally as lobg